# Testing Equality of boto Price object

Tags: python, boto, mechanicalturk

I am using the python package boto to connect python to MTurk. I am needing to award bonus payments, which are of the Price type. I want to test if one Price object equals a certain value. Specifically, when I want to award bonus payments, I need to check that their bonus payment is not 0 (because when you try to award a bonus payment in MTurk, it needs to be positive). But when I go to check values, I can't do this. For example,

```
from boto.mturk.connection import MTurkConnection
from boto.mturk.price import Price
a = Price(0)
a == 0
a == Price(0)
a == Price(0.0)
a > Price(0)
a < Price(0)
c = Price(.05)
c < Price(0)
c < Price(0.0)
```

These yield unexpected answers.

I am not sure of how to test if a has a Price equal to 0. Any suggestions?

Comment: Figured it out - need to do `a.amount`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think you'll want the Price.amount function to compare these values. Otherwise, I think it compares objects or some other goofiness. It'd be smart for the library to override the standard quality test to make this more developer-friendly.